# Win 2008 R2 Server Not Recognizing Second Hard Drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, windows-server-2008-r2, windows

I just purchased a Dell server, which has two hard drives and no RAID setup.  I can only currently see one hard drive... not sure how to get it to recognize the other, as I thought being a new machine that wouldn't be an issue.

It has Windows Server 2008 R2 that I loaded on.  I'm a n00b to all of this so I'm not sure why this is failing to work...

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you go into the RAID configuration, can the RAID controller see both disks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialise disks before Windows can see them.

Go into *Server Manager* and from the left menu, under *Storage* choose *Disk Management*.

If you can see the disk in there, right click on it and select *Online*. Choose a partition style and press **OK**. Once you've done that, you can go ahead and create a partition on the new drive.

*(This is from memory/Google, so apologies if things are a little bit in the wrong order)*

Comment: There wasn't an Online option, it had a Simple Storage option, and using that created and formatted the volume.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see the second drive in Bios? If not, you likely got a broken unit of some sort. Happens. Bios autodetection should show you all the drives.

Comment: Yes, its showing up there and in the hardware config.  Turns out it needed formatted.